# TextJoin: How to remove duplicate values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table of data:

[image]

In C2, I then input the following formula `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$7=$B2,$A$2:$A$7,""))` which returns the following:

[image]

However, I want the formula to ignore any duplicates and just return `1, 30`

I've had a peruse, and looked a similarly asked questions on here, but i am unable to get anything to work

## **EDIT**

I have partially resolved this with the following code:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$13=$B2,IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13,0)=ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$2)+1,$A$2:$A$13,""),""))`

However, if the ID code changes and an income code, previously populated under a different ID, appears it will just return blank:

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: There seems to be an swer to your question here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/removing-duplicates-when-using-textjoin/m-p/188950

Comment: If you don't have the `UNIQUE` function, you can create the results using Power Query. Of course, it won't be dynamic like formulas would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, try this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) instead :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$13=$B2,IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0)=ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$2)+1,$A$2:$A$13,""),""))
```

Answer (score 1):

***Applies to O365 with the `UNIQUE` function***

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF($B$2:$B$7=$B2,IF($A$2:$A$7="","",$A$2:$A$7),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Ron. I attempted the above, but i don't seem to have the unique function even though i do have Office 365.

Comment: @Jason I'll see if I can come up with an equivalent for the earlier versions.  I'd have thought they'd all be updated by now.